# Impala invalidate metadata through jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, metadata, impala, invalidation

Is there any way to invalidate metadata on Impala through jdbc?

I've tried the following (I am using Cloudera_ImpalaJDBC4_2.5.5.1007 driver):

```
            // invalidate metadata and rebuild index on Impala 
            try {
                Statement stmt = impalaConn.createStatement();
                try {
                    String query = "INVALIDATE METADATA;";
                    ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        // do something
                    }
                }                
                finally {
                    stmt.close();
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException ex) {
                while (ex != null)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    ex = ex.getNextException();
                }
                System.exit(1);
            }
```

but I got the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: [Simba][JDBC](11300) A ResultSet was expected but not generated from query "INVALIDATE METADATA;". Query not executed.
        at com.cloudera.impala.exceptions.ExceptionConverter.toSQLException(ExceptionConverter.java:136)
        at com.cloudera.impala.jdbc.common.SStatement.checkCondition(SStatement.java:2274)
        at com.cloudera.impala.jdbc.common.SStatement.executeNoParams(SStatement.java:2704)
        at com.cloudera.impala.jdbc.common.SStatement.executeQuery(SStatement.java:880)
        at ico.az.deploy.TestSuite.testTeradata(TestSuite.java:103)
        at ico.az.deploy.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:310)
        at ico.az.deploy.TestSuite.main(TestSuite.java:345)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. That query doesn't return a `ResultSet`. Use [`Statement.executeUpdate(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) instead. As the JavaDoc notes, bold added for emphasis, *Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement **or an SQL statement that returns nothing***.

```
stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```